# Google places API parsing problems

Tags: android, json, google-places-api

I am using google places API and in the parsing I am using JSON, but this line

```
JsonHttpParser parser = new JsonHttpParser(new JacksonFactory());
request.addParser(parser);
```

is deprecated. Is there any way to fix or any alternative way?

Here's the function:

```
public Placeslist search(double latitude, double longitude, double radius, String types)
        throws Exception {

    try {
        HttpRequestFactory httpRequestFactory = createRequestFactory(HTTP_TRANSPORT);
        HttpRequest request = httpRequestFactory
                .buildGetRequest(new GenericUrl(PLACES_SEARCH_URL));
        request.getUrl().put("key", API_KEY);
        request.getUrl().put("location", _latitude + "," + _longitude);
        request.getUrl().put("radius", _radius);  
        request.getUrl().put("sensor", "false");
        if(types != null)
            request.getUrl().put("types", types);

        Placeslist list = request.execute().parseAs(Placeslist.class);
        // Check log cat for places response status
        Log.d("Places Status", "" + list.status);
        return list;
    } catch (HttpResponseException e) {
        Log.e("Error:", e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
}  

// Creating http request Factory  
public static HttpRequestFactory createRequestFactory(
        final HttpTransport transport) {
    return transport.createRequestFactory(new HttpRequestInitializer() {
        public void initialize(HttpRequest request) {
            GoogleHeaders headers = new GoogleHeaders();
            headers.setApplicationName("Google-Places-Test");
            request.setHeaders(headers);
            JsonHttpParser parser = new JsonHttpParser(new JacksonFactory());
            request.addParser(parser);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that class `JsonHttpParser` and method `HttpRequest` were both deprecated in version 1.11. See [The Deprecated list](http://javadoc.google-http-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/1.10.2-beta/deprecated-list.html) for more information.

So instead of:

```
JsonHttpParser parser = new JsonHttpParser(new JacksonFactory());
request.addParser(parser);
```

You would now have:

```
JsonObjectParser parser = new JsonObjectParser(new JacksonFactory());
request.setParser(parser);
```

And change your import to:

```
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonObjectParser;
```

EDIT: I have tested this and it works for me.